# How to pass value of boolean to Generic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, types

I am trying to pass a boolean value to the Generic type, which will be used inside a condition.

This is the generic type

```
interface OptionTypeBase {
    [key: string]: any;
}

type OptionsType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase> = ReadonlyArray<OptionType>;

export type ValueType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase, IsMulti extends boolean> = IsMulti extends true
    ? OptionsType<OptionType>
    : OptionType | null;
```

In my React component, I have a **isMulti** prop, which I get from the parent component.
How can I pass the value of the **isMulti**, so that the above-mentioned generic type could correctly infer the type for a condition ?

I have already tried to do it this way, but seems it is wrong.

```
ValueType<IOption<T>, typeof isMulti>
```

Comment: What is `OptionTypeBase`?

Comment: Please, see the update version.

Comment: Are you going to affect *static* typing by *runtime* value? I don't think it's possible

Comment: Then how the hell does that conditional type works? Actually, it is inside react-select library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should totally consider not doing this, because I'm pretty sure this will be a pain in the neck, but you can do it by making `isMulti` itself generic. This should work:

```
const MyComponent = <T extends any, IsMulti extends boolean>(
  {option, isMulti}: {option: T, isMulti: IsMulti}
) => {
  const a: ValueType<IOption<T>, IsMulti> = ...
  return <div></div>
}
```

Comment: In this case , what would be the **ValueType<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase, IsMulti extends boolean>** equal ? It is conditional and depending on IsMulti it returns **OptionsType<OptionType>** or **OptionType | null**  ?